# Cordova - Can't add platform

Tags: android, apache, web, ant, cordova

My environment :

```
 - Windows 7 64bits
 - Cordova 3.2.0-0.4.0
 - Android SDK Build-tools: 19
 - Android SDK Tools: 2.33
 - Apache Ant : 1.9.2
```

My PATH is correctly configured.

On CLI > cordova platform add android
Checking Android requirements

```
[Error: An error occured while listing Android targets]
```

I deleted the `.cordova`, but can't added android platform

Comment: are you go through this one http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Comment: I use the Windows CLI for generate my Cordova project.

Comment: I have tried in ubuntu terminal but i got error then do it in manually like my ref got success...

Comment: It's old method ? for Cordova 2.0, no? In Cordova 3.2, i don't have cordova-2.0.0.js and cordova-2.0.0.jar

Comment: download here http://phonegap.com/install/

Comment: But, is'nt the best practice for use Cordova, I want to use the CLI for generate my project, build, ...

Comment: This link for solve my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323787/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-while-listing-android-targets/20422750?noredirect=1#comment30614691_20422750

Comment: Is that wrong to do like in the reference document..