# Cordova add platform android on debian wheezy

Tags: android, linux, cordova, debian

I try run this command

$ cordova platform add android

But, generate this error

$ Checking Android requirements...

$ [Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets]

What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323787/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-while-listing-android-targets

Comment: Can you do `cordova platform add android -d` to see more logging information? Do you have ant, npm, and java installed? What happens when you run `android`? I think you will need to set up an avd by running `android` then going to "Tools" then "Setup AVD"