# Cordova - add android platform issue

Tags: cordova, command-line, environment-variables, adt

I am currently in the process of setting up cordova and adding the android platform to build my project. I have added `ant` and `java` to my environment paths and they work fine in the command line.

The error i receive when trying to run `cordova platform add android` is the following

```
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
at C:\Users\currys\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js: 87:29
at _rejected (C:\Users\currys\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
at C:\Users\currys\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
at Promise.when (C:\Users\currys\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\currys\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
at C:\Users\currys\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
at flush (C:\Users\currys\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\currys\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I found another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323787/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-while-listing-android-targets) that mentioned I should add the `ANDROID_HOME` variable to my environment variables. I have added the following to my variables but so far nothing else has changed.

```
ANDROID_HOME
C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk
```

Then I added the following to my path variable

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
```

Is anything I have done so far incorrect? Or am i missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
```

to

```
%ANDROID_HOME%;
```

Comment: Wow that worked! I don't see why their isn't a decent tutorial anywhere on this! Thank you, you have saved my day!!

Comment: In my case, it is not working :(( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422961/cordova-cannot-add-android-failed-with-exit-code-enoent