# Cordova cannot add Android failed with exit code ENOENT

Tags: android, cordova, path, cordova-3

I am trying to create an Android project with Cordova, however i am getting an ENOENT error although i followed the tutorial step by step very carefully, this is getting me angry.
First this is the screenshot of the error:
[image]
Here are information about my software and hardware/os:

**Hardware and OS:**

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60 GHz 2.60GHz
- 4 GB RAM
- 64 bit operating system, x 64 based processor
- Windows 8

**Software:**
Here are some of the outputs of my command line for the related software.

- $ npm -version
- Output: 1.4.8
- $ cordova -version
- Output: 3.4.1-0.1.0
- $ ant -version
- Output: Apache Ant(TM) Version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
- $ java -version

[image]

- $ adb version
- Output: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31

**Here are some of my system variables:**

- ANDROID_HOME:  C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk
- ANT_HOME: C:\apache-ant-1.9.3
- JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
- CLASSPATH: %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
- PATH:
  %JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\app\barisa\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program
  Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
  Client\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
  Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
  Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
  Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
  Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management
  Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
  Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
  Pages\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows
  Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
  Server\110\DTS\Binn\;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools;C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\tools;C:\Program
  Files\nodejs\
- Note: I copied the tools.jar from jdk/lib to jre/lib after some
  research on the internet. Not working.
- Note 2: I give the command "cd
  C:\Users\barisa.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin" There is a
  check_reqs file in that folder. However if i type $ chek_reqs in the
  command line it says "check_reqs is not recognized as an internal or
  external command ...."
- Note 3: I opened command propmt (cmd) by right click -> run as
  administrator What should i do?

Extra information with -d flag:

[image]

### Update

I cleaned .cordova and reinstalled it and now, i am getting this error:
[image]

My variables are defined as indicated above.

Comment: have you solved this issue?

Comment: yes, i solved it. the order of paths in the environment variable were important. since i quitted my job, i cannot tell the order of variables. but advise you to check them twice.

Comment: my order of paths is correct.But no idea still getting same error.

Comment: Then please give us right order of path friend

Answer (score 8):

If you are sure of yours paths try to type android in cmd if it says: 'xcopy' was not recognized.

then add to your path:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32; %SystemRoot%; %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
```

In certain cases, don't forget to reboot the PC.

Comment: In my case, I had to restart the PC :) (I am on WIndows OS).

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just needed to add "C:\Windows\System32" to my windows path.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when trying ionic platform add android.

result;
partial build with ENOENT error titled `"cordova-plugin-console" on the same child process as mentioned above superspawn.js`

After trying reinstalling etc.. without resolution I changed my path variables around.
ANDROID_HOME was placed in user variables --

`C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk`

PATH was updated in the system variables to remove previous entries for SDK and added at the end;
`%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Users\XXXXXX\Node\;C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;`

Restart pc, tested with new app
`ionic start <new folder> tabs`
cd to the folder created,
test it runs with
`ionic serve --lab`
exit with q then try to add the platform.
`ionic platform add android`

now it works..

Please note********* now when i run 'android' in the CMD from my user dir... 
`C:\Users\XXXXX>android`

i do not see the xcopy not found displayed to my screen.
android SDK manager always loaded before and still now after i changed my paths.

Hope this helps p.s I run these cmds from my user acc which is not the admin acc as i never log in as or use my pc as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow these steps:

1. run the command: npm uninstall cordova -g
2. delete the folder: C:\Users\your-name\.cordova
3. reinstall the cordova: npm install -g cordova
4. now go to the project folder and try again: cordova platform add android

Comment: After trying everything its the cordova update that worked for me : npm update -g cordova

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that if you created PATH as a system variable, you should run Command Prompt as administrator.

I created PATH as a user variable, and would get the same error when tryin to run as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was user variable **TEMP**. There were two folders.

**Not working TEMP -path:**

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\php
```

**Working TEMP -path:**

```
 %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

After this everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error days ago with cordova version 3.1.Go to directory path C:\Program Files\nodejs and then install your cordova.Sometimes cordova cannot connect to the right path of npm due to conflict.Then create your project and add platform android.Hope this solution works for you too.

Comment: hi.thanks for the suggesstion. i went to the c:\program files\nodejs directory and uninstalled the cordova with the command "$ npm uninstall cordova -g"  then within the same directory i installed it with the command "$ npm install cordova -g". then i created a brand new project and i tried to add platform android. however i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just run cmd with as Administrator and execute 'cordova platform add android' command and now work fine.