# ionic platform error when adding android platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add android platform to ionic but when I add it keeps getting this error

```
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.ionicframework.carmart632655
        Name: CarMart
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-23
Android project created with cordova-android@5.1.1
Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-console':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\UVINDU\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

What is wrong with my installation

Comment: You are connected with internet when adding platform?

Comment: Yes I have connected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova cannot add Android failed with exit code ENOENT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422961/cordova-cannot-add-android-failed-with-exit-code-enoent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in Windows usually this kind of error happens when you don't have all the paths required in your system environment path variable . Especially the path variables given bellow.

Please paste this line on your system environment Path variable:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32;
```

You can also check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm2Quz_Gzhk) out. There is the total installation tutorial.

Comment: You should explain what this does

Answer (score 0):

Firstly uninstall node.js and reinstall freshly after that execute that following command.

```
ionic start {your project directory} --v2
```

Here one case i observed if you have any plugins required for your project try to install before adding platform, otherwise we are getting some error just like as below.

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-console':Error: cmd: Command failed
>   with exit code ENOENT
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:7)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
>       at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT.

once plugin's installation done try to add platform it should work.

Make sure that to avoid the below error, just copy "C:\Windows\System32" this to PATH environment variable and close the current active command prompt and open try once.(If not working still try to reboot and check)

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT.

Answer (score -1):

Have you setup your android studio with right version of adt tools downloaded?