# Error when i try to install android Platform at ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I got the below error when trying to add Android platform to Ionic framework. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Cordova, but the problem persists.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you're obviously working on Windows:
Is your issue possibly related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831690/ionic-platform-error-when-adding-android-platform)?

EDIT: this at last solved the issue:

Add JAVA_OPTS as a system variable:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

After that, head over to your CMD and run the following command:

```
SET JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

Try again. ;)

Comment: Yes is the same issue. I install step by step java, android studio, node js, Cordova and ionic like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm2Quz_Gzhk video but the problem is still occurred.

Comment: So have you tried adding the line to your environment variable as proposed in the linked post?

Comment: mh okay so this might also be related to a gradle issue.. it's just a guess, but could you try to delete

Comment: .. sorry, submitted to fast.. so could you try to delete (just in case back it up somewhere) your .gradle from C:\Users\<username> directory, restart your CMD and try again?

Comment: okay, one last guess, otherwise I'm out of ideas I'm afraid: increase the heap size for Java on your machine.

Therefore add JAVA_OPTS as a system variable:

    JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"

After that, head over to your CMD and run the following command:

    SET JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"

Try again. ;)

Comment: I edited the answer to contain the solution - would you be so kind and mark it as correct? :)