# Creating a Cordova project on lubuntu

Tags: java, android, cordova

I checked to see if I had the requirements to create a new Cordova project on lubuntu and I receved an error. I don't quite understand the error I received:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

At first I thought I could just ignore it for now and when I would create the project t explain the error further but it didn't clear it up any further. I searched the Internet but none of the suggestions seemed to solve my problem. Could someone explain to me how I could fix this problem. If anyone needs further information (more specific information) tell me and I will happily share it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova cannot add Android failed with exit code ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422961/cordova-cannot-add-android-failed-with-exit-code-enoent)

Comment: @CyprienAubry I had already seen that post, I didn't quite understand how his problem was fixed or even if it got fixed. Besides he was using windows and I'm on Linux so the solution will vary.

Comment: The error seems conming from the environement vars. Do you have checked that point?