# Command failed with exit code enoent on IONIC 4

Tags: android, gradle, npm, ionic4

The error on the above title only occurs on this specific project, when I build a Blank project it doesn't get this error. I've tried the other solutions to this problem but I just can't seem to get this working.

Heres the error message:

```
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle-5.6.2\bin\gradle.bat" -p C:\Windows\System32\QRID2\qrid\platforms\android wrapper -b C:\Windows\System32\QRID2\qrid\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle""
Command finished with error code ENOENT: cmd /s /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle-5.6.2\bin\gradle.bat" -p C:\Windows\System32\QRID2\qrid\platforms\android wrapper -b C:\Windows\System32\QRID2\qrid\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle"
cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Windows\System32\QRID2\qrid\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova cannot add Android failed with exit code ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422961/cordova-cannot-add-android-failed-with-exit-code-enoent)

Comment: it's likely an `npm` issue... not a Gradle issue.

Comment: This error only occurs when I build the project though.

Comment: when it happens does not matter; `cordova` itself is just an `npm` package. and the approaches there look way more promising than they look here.

Comment: Can you suggest a possible solution?

Comment: I'd suspect the version of Cordova not being compatible with the version of NodeJS used - or the `$PATH` not being setup properly.

Comment: It still does not work, I'm desperate for help now.

Comment: it's really difficult to tell by that error, which is being thrown by nodeJS... try running `"C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle-5.6.2\bin\gradle.bat" -p C:\Windows\System32\QRID2\qrid\platforms\android wrapper -b C:\Windows\System32\QRID2\qrid\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle"` in a DOS box... and also check the Gradle version inside the `wrapper.gradle`, which might be used. or go into that `android` directory and try running `gradlew.bat assembleDebug`. this both might turn up a tad more information why.

Comment: the mere question is, if it fails when preparing platform `android`, or if it fails when trying to build with Gradle, or if it's not able to find the correct version of NodeJS. this question does not feature a single version number ...it could as well be, that it cannot parse the `config.xml`, when preparing.

Answer (score 0):

This means **ENOENT**  `Error NO ENTity|ENTry` so such derectory

check your `gradle` is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle-5.6.2`

Comment: Gradle is located in that directory. What should I do?

Comment: can you post gradle derectory path

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\gradle-5.6.2

Comment: do you have gradle.zip file windows: setx CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL ../gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Comment: set your zip file

Comment: Where is that found?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the gradle installed on your machine?

**Try it:**

**1 - download the gradle from the site [gradle.org](https://gradle.org).**

Download the .zip file and extract to disk C:\

**2 - Set the Gradle Environment Variables.**

In order for the Gradle executable to be visible on the Windows command line, you must set the **GRADLE_HOME** variable and expose it in the system path.

*Example:*

```
variable name: GRADLE_HOME

variable value: c:\gradle-2.5
```

and then add GRADLE_HOME to Path

```
;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin
```

Restart your PC and use de command line

```
gradle -version
```

To see if it works