# Failed to run JAVA even though path is set on Windows 8 Enterprise - Cordova

Tags: java, android, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I have made a new Ionic / Cordova project and I'm trying to build it on windows 8.1. I installed JDK and JRE 7 as well as android sdk and ant and added them to my path using the following instructions.

[cordova platform add android not working while listing Android targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323787/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-while-listing-android-targets/20333029#20333029)

When I execute `ionic platform add android` or `cordova` I am still getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\BogdanR\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Failed to run 'java -version', make sure your java environment is set up
including JDK and JRE.
Your JAVA_HOME variable is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
Error: Command failed: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.


    at C:\Users\BogdanR\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:62:22
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\nodist\bin\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
Unable to add platform android. Please see console for more info.
```

I tried modifying both system variables and user PATH variables.

THE WEIRD THING is that I can type in `java -version` and it works:

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

I am using nodist to manage npm if that is of any relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bad entry in the path that corrupted my whole system path.

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn";C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;`

Seems like that quotation mark is an entry added by SQL Server installation or web platform. I never added those to the path so it might be the installers fault?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. I am not sure what is corrupting my path, but I moved "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin;" to the front of my path and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 15):

After I ran into the same issue, the following steps seems to have fixed it:

- `PATH` needs to contain the bin folder of the Java installation path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin` make sure the `bin` is included
- `JAVA_HOME` needs to be set to the root of that Java installation folder, in my case `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i had multiple java instalations, and whenever i tried to print "echo %java_home%" command on command prompt, it always used to return "%java_home%" as it is.

So i uninstalled all the java versions and then installed it again, and whoola, it worked.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

There is one thing you can try is to set this variable JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin

Since you are using Windows, you can go to Control Panel to update it.

You were able to run `java -version` probably because it's included in the User's path.

Comment: had the same issue - chucked the path to java in the beginning and all is now well - must be an bodged entry in PATH

Answer (score 1):

In my case, It said "JAVA_HOME variable is unvalid, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51".
Then I added a quotation mark to JAVA_HOME. Just like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51". Finally It works. May This can be helpful