# Ionic can not build android

Tags: java, android, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-framework

I am a starter to Ionic. When i build myfirst ionic app, i meet error.

```
 Error:Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.

 Error:D:\andorid\ionic\test\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: command failed with exit code 2

      at ChildProcess.whenDone <C:\users\L\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\suoerspawn.js:131:23>
      at ChildProcess. emit <events.js:110:17>
      at maybeClose <child_process.js:1008:16>
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit <child_process.js:1080:5>
```

Actulally my java environment was installed correctly. I can run "java -version".

```
Java version "1.8.0_20"
Java<TM> SE Runtime Environment <build 1.8.0_20-b26>
Java HotSpot<TM> 64-Bit Server VM <build 25.20-b23,mixed mode>
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What is your ant version? ant -version

Comment: @Aks My ant version is 1.9.4

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868472/failed-to-run-java-even-though-path-is-set-on-windows-8-enterprise-cordova might help

Comment: @Aks Thx a lot!  I have solved it by myself. I install JDK and JRE in different directory. After I reinstall JDK, ionic build successfully.

Comment: I used the most simple and crude method to configure Android environment,directly install Android studio to guarantee environment ok.

Answer (score 5):

## Try this

Open .bash_profile file with this

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

After adding

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```