# Apache Cordova jdk missing Failed to run javac -version

Tags: java, cordova, javac, apache-cordova

I need your help. I am trying to install the apache cordova and to create the first application using the tutorialspoint help. 
As can you see I have jdk but cordova can not build the app.
Do you know why?
[This is what command prompt answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP6D5.png)

Comment: Launch command "cordova requirements" from CMD and check if all requisites are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/eb5or8 these are the results. I have the jdk but cordova can not see it. I also have android sdk and I have this variable as you can see. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: For android you need to download android-sdk for API level of our build. Launch ANDROID command on CMD then download SDK by checking appropriate SDK (es API21). For java problem, have you added JAVA_HOME on your PATH system variable? try to "ECHO %PATH%" on CMD and check.

Comment: And try to reboot /relogon user when you add JAVA_HOME to system PATH variable. You also need ADT_HOME (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk) instead of ANDROID_HOME system variable and add this to PATH same of JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am now downloading API and roms of android. But for java I can not understand what are you proposing me. http://prntscr.com/eb67en This is the ECHO PATH on CMD. What do you meen to add JAVA_HOME on PATH system variable? How can I do this? Should I add %JAVA_HOME% to PATH?

Comment: Hmm no, you already have JAVA_HOME on path. Try to add quotation marks to JAVA_HOME ("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121") as reported [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868472/failed-to-run-java-even-though-path-is-set-on-windows-8-enterprise-cordova):  sometimes the space in "program files" path cause some issues..

Comment: Neither this solution works for me. Thanks for the help... I hope to find the solution.