# Error While Running Phonegap application in Intellij IDE

Tags: android, cordova, intellij-idea

While I am running phonegap Application in IntellijIDE i am getting following error..i tried many ways and set the SDK path as said in statcoverflow 
[cordova platform add android not working while listing Android targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323787/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-while-listing-android-targets).

But still i am getting error as follows

/home/swift-03/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;

```
                  ^
```

Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets

```
at /home/swift-03/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29

at _rejected (/home/swift-03/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)

at /home/swift-03/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30

at Promise.when (/home/swift-03/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)

at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/swift-03/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)

at /home/swift-03/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44

at flush (/home/swift-03/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.1/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)

at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

can anyone please help me..Thanks in advance