# phonegap build android: ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existent path

Tags: android, cordova

I have the odd problem that "ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existent oath", while I can `dir` that path.

Let me give you a walk-through for my cmd commands:

```
Z:\phonegap-test-app>phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
Running command: Z:\phonegap-test-app\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat

Error: Z:\phonegap-test-app\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed 
with exit code 2
```

Okay, dunno what exit code 2 is, so let's try to execute build.bat:

```
Z:\phonegap-test-app>Z:\phonegap-test-app\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existant path: "C:\Users\alexander.urban\Ap
pData\Local\Android\android-sdk"]
```

So I misspelled something in the path. Just that I C&P'ed it from the Explorer, so no misspelling today. C&P to the DIR command will show this as well:

```
Z:\phonegap-test-app>dir "C:\Users\alexander.urban\AppData\Local\Android\android
-sdk"
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist WINDOWS
 Volumeseriennummer: 28B2-7DF4

 Verzeichnis von C:\Users\alexander.urban\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

24.11.2014  09:16    <DIR>          .
24.11.2014  09:16    <DIR>          ..
24.11.2014  10:07    <DIR>          add-ons
02.07.2014  20:03           220.209 AVD Manager.exe
24.11.2014  08:58    <DIR>          build-tools
24.11.2014  09:04    <DIR>          docs
24.11.2014  09:10    <DIR>          extras
24.11.2014  08:58    <DIR>          platform-tools
24.11.2014  09:06    <DIR>          platforms
24.11.2014  09:08    <DIR>          samples
02.07.2014  20:03           220.721 SDK Manager.exe
02.07.2014  20:03             1.170 SDK Readme.txt
24.11.2014  09:09    <DIR>          sources
24.11.2014  09:45    <DIR>          system-images
24.11.2014  10:07    <DIR>          temp
24.11.2014  09:12    <DIR>          tools
24.11.2014  08:53            71.075 uninstall.exe
               4 Datei(en),        513.175 Bytes
              13 Verzeichnis(se), 19.706.216.448 Bytes frei
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

EDIT:

```
Z:\phonegap-test-app>set ANDROID_HOME="C:\Users\alexander.urban\AppData\Local\An
droid\android-sdk"
```

Comment: Have you set the ANDROID_HOME var in your environment? What does it display when you call `set ANDROID_HOME` command?

Comment: @QuickFix: Edited into the entry.

Comment: not clear where you set the env var (in the windows system parameters for user/for all system, in a cmd?). In a new cmd, does the `set ANDROID_HOME` command return you the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had struggle with this for a lot of time and finally the following post by I.cotonea helped:

Refer: [cordova platform add android not working while listing Android targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20323787/cordova-platform-add-android-not-working-while-listing-android-targets)